# Perl LibXML to get node value report uninitialized

Tags: perl, libxml2, xml-libxml

I try to get the node value using LibXML,

Returns below log:

```
Use of uninitialized value $long_name in concatenation (.) or string at validate.0.1.pl line 105, <FILEHD> line 1.
###LI### 11 node_ln is: <annotation source="Name" xml:lang="EN">TestValue</annotation> and long_name is .
```

Script:

```
use XML::LibXML;
....
for my $node_ln ($xpc->findnodes( qq(.//xsd:annotation[\@source=\"Name\"]), $node_root)){
    my $long_name = $node_ln->nodeValue;
    print("###LI### 11 node_ln is: $node_ln and long_name is $long_name.\n");
}
```

Scratching my head now on how to get the node value 'TestValue', any suggestion? Thank you all!

Comment: Sample data would be helpful for this. But how about `$node_ln -> textContent;`

Comment: @Sobrique, You are a genius!